# What are the applications of fractional convolutions to physics - if any?

Tags: operators, fourier-transform, mathematics, signal-processing

There are multiple [applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Applications) of the convolution operation to physics. For instance, it comes about in calculations in fluorescence spectroscopy, acoustics, and computational fluid dynamics.

The above are applications of the 'classical' convolution, in which a sum of a discrete amount of random variables or generalized distributions. I wonder whether a certain generalization of the convolution operator also has applications to certain research areas in physics: the fractional convolution.

The fractional convolution was described by David Mustard in a [1995 paper](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0334270000012509) ([PDF](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/5F77E68A692F334232326450D3040334/S0334270000012509a.pdf/fractional_convolution.pdf)). It builds on notions of a [fractional Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform). Although physical applications of the latter have been investigated - to quantum physics, for instance - I haven't been able to find any application of the fractional convolution operation so far.

**Question**: are there any applications of fractional convolution to physics? If so, what do they entail?